# Updating a data attribute of a TR with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read many of the answers and I am still not quite sure how to update an attribute of a TR.  The idea of my code is to combine similar rows into one while updating the first row's data-auditidentity attribute.

What in the blue blazes am I missing??  The end result should be one table row for procedure and the data-auditidentity property should have all four comma separated keys.  Trying to update using attr to have all four values comma separated fails.

```js
var uniqueKeys = [];
var resultsTable = $('#results');
$(resultsTable).find('tbody > tr').each(function() {

  var tableName = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var tableAction = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
  var uniqueKey = tableName + '#' + tableAction;

  if (uniqueKeys.indexOf(uniqueKey) < 0) {
    uniqueKeys.push(uniqueKey);
  } else {

    var initValue = '',
      newCombinedValues = '',
      auditidentity = '';
    initValue = $(resultsTable).find(" tr td:first-child:contains(" + tableName + ")").parent().attr('data-auditidentity');

    var activityLogId = $(this).data('activitylogid');
    auditidentity = $(this).data('auditidentity');

    newCombinedValues = initValue + "," + auditidentity;

    $(resultsTable).find("tbody tr td:first:contains(" + tableName + ")").parent().attr('data-auditidentity', newCombinedValues);

    // After we have what we need, remove the combined row as we are combining the keys into one row
    //$(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all" data-auditidentity="18487179,18487183">
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487186" data-auditid="f831583e-d1a9-4e35-ac92-82a5cb48c62e">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Selection</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487179" data-auditid="88506880-632f-4e17-bceb-ebd4e20e435a">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487181" data-auditid="a2768380-8c4a-4070-9834-900f95db77a2">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487182" data-auditid="cb54deca-2bc4-4b71-ba5a-0e6d075b7b26">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487183" data-auditid="05803858-aaba-4f9b-9128-fc0c265cfaf6">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The END RESULT SHOULD BE THIS

```
<table id="results">
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all" data-auditidentity="18487179,18487183">
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487186" data-auditid="f831583e-d1a9-4e35-ac92-82a5cb48c62e">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Selection</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487179,18487181,18487182,18487183" data-auditid="88506880-632f-4e17-bceb-ebd4e20e435a">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: So basically you want to check "data-auditidentity" for each row and keep first row of each unique value and remove other existing rows with same "data-auditidentity" attribute?

Comment: @FaridNaderi The data-auditidentity will be unique. I want to combine the four rows into one, and update the single data-auditidentity to have all four keys, comma separated. Updated my question for further clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it correctly but can you see if it works for you ? 
`var uniqueKeys = [];
 $('table tr').each(function(index){
 uniqueKeys.push($(this).data('auditidentity'));
 if(index >0 ) {
  $(this).remove();
 }
 }); 
 $('table tr')
 .data('auditidentity',uniqueKeys.join())
 .attr('data-auditidentity',uniqueKeys.join());
`

Comment: Be careful about mixing `.attr()` and `.data()`. I think the code you have is safe, but it's best to be consistent.

Comment: @Barmar i have tried both and neither works for me in updating the value

Comment: Could you turn the code in your post into a more complete [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can try running it and making modifications?

Comment: Can I suggest you break your non functioning line into many pieces and debug to discover which part of the expression is failing? Even typing pieces of it into the console in debug mode. My javascript never works first time. It takes a kit of experimentation in the console to get anything to work.

Comment: @Barmar I got the question cleaned up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the selector `$(resultsTable).find("tbody tr td:first:contains(" + tableName + ")")`. `:first` means to select the first `td` in the whole document, not the first `td` in each row. This should be `:first-child`. Then you need to use `:first` after that to select the first of all these in the document. So the whole selector should be `resultsTable.find("tbody tr td:first-child:contains(" + tableName + "):first")`

BTW, you don't need to wrap `resultsTable` in `$()`. It's already a jQuery object.

```js
var uniqueKeys = [];
var resultsTable = $('#results');
$(resultsTable).find('tbody > tr').each(function() {

  var tableName = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var tableAction = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
  var uniqueKey = tableName + '#' + tableAction;

  if (uniqueKeys.indexOf(uniqueKey) < 0) {
    uniqueKeys.push(uniqueKey);
  } else {

    var initValue = '',
      newCombinedValues = '',
      auditidentity = '';
    initValue = resultsTable.find(" tr td:first-child:contains(" + tableName + ")").parent().attr('data-auditidentity');

    var activityLogId = $(this).data('activitylogid');
    auditidentity = $(this).data('auditidentity');

    newCombinedValues = initValue + "," + auditidentity;

    resultsTable.find("tbody tr td:first-child:contains(" + tableName + "):first").parent().attr('data-auditidentity', newCombinedValues);

    // After we have what we need, remove the combined row as we are combining the keys into one row
    //$(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all" data-auditidentity="18487179,18487183">
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487186" data-auditid="f831583e-d1a9-4e35-ac92-82a5cb48c62e">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Selection</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487179" data-auditid="88506880-632f-4e17-bceb-ebd4e20e435a">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487181" data-auditid="a2768380-8c4a-4070-9834-900f95db77a2">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487182" data-auditid="cb54deca-2bc4-4b71-ba5a-0e6d075b7b26">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487183" data-auditid="05803858-aaba-4f9b-9128-fc0c265cfaf6">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the tip on the jQuery object too!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var uniqueKeys = [];
var resultsTable = $('#results');
$(resultsTable).find('tbody > tr').each(function() {

 var currentAuditIdentity = $(this).data().auditidentity;
  var currentActivityLogId = $(this).data().activitylogid;
  var tableName = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var tableAction = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
  var uniqueKey = {'Name': tableName, 'Action': tableAction, 'AuditIdentity':currentAuditIdentity, 'ActivityLogId':currentActivityLogId};

 var matchingElements = $.grep(uniqueKeys, function(item){
    return (item != null && item.Name == uniqueKey.Name && item.Action == uniqueKey.Action);
  });
  if (matchingElements.length == 0) {
    uniqueKeys.push(uniqueKey);
  }
  else {
  matchingElements[0].AuditIdentity += ',' + currentAuditIdentity;
    // After we have what we need, remove the combined row as we are combining the keys into one row
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
//Finally, put the latest data back into the remaining unique rows
$.each(uniqueKeys, function(index, value){
  var item = $(resultsTable).find('tr').find('td:eq(0):contains("' + value.Name + '")').parent();
     item.data().auditidentity = value.AuditIdentity;
});
//Just to show the data result.
$('span#showArrayData').text(JSON.stringify(uniqueKeys));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all" data-auditidentity="18487179,18487183">
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487186" data-auditid="f831583e-d1a9-4e35-ac92-82a5cb48c62e">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Selection</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487179" data-auditid="88506880-632f-4e17-bceb-ebd4e20e435a">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487181" data-auditid="a2768380-8c4a-4070-9834-900f95db77a2">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487182" data-auditid="cb54deca-2bc4-4b71-ba5a-0e6d075b7b26">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487183" data-auditid="05803858-aaba-4f9b-9128-fc0c265cfaf6">
    <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<span id="showArrayData"></span>
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of jQuery code,

```
var uniqueRows = {}; 
 $('table tr').each(function(){
    var tdValue = $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
    if(!uniqueRows[tdValue]){
        uniqueRows[tdValue] = $(this); 
    } else {
        uniqueRows[tdValue].data('auditidentity',
            uniqueRows[tdValue].data('auditidentity')+','+$(this).data('auditidentity'));
        $(this).remove(); 
    }
 });
```

Please make sure you select correct table in your code.
Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't combine the data attribute of the rows that are being combined. It concatenates all the data attributes of all rows, and then sets that on all the rows.

Comment: as it removes all rows except first row, at the time of resetting the attribute its only one row, and this is what I understood from his question and comments :)

Comment: He's only combining rows that have the same text content, not combining all the rows of the table.

Comment: this is what he wrote in his post `The end result should be one table row for procedure`, or I didn't understand correct ?:P

Comment: @MisterPositive I just updated this, can you try it again?

Comment: He wrote **The idea of my code is to combine similar rows into one**. "Procedure" is just an example of similar rows.

Comment: Ok ty for pointing that, the updated answer should do what he asked for then. :)